# Simplifying $e^{\ln a} - e^{\ln 0.1 + \ln b}$ into logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was wondering if this:$$e^{\ln a} - e^{\ln 0.1 + \ln b}$$can be written using only logarithms as this:$$\ln a - \ln 0.1 - \ln b$$

If this is wrong, is there a way to express the expression above using only logarithms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be :
$$\exp(\ln(a))-\exp(\ln(0.1)+\ln(b))=\exp(\ln(a))-\exp(\ln(0.1b))=a-0.1b$$
Is this what you meant? So no logatrithms are even needed.

Comment: Hi Teun, no I actually needed only logarithms… Can I then log this?a - 0.1b = ln(a) - 0.1*ln(b) ?

Comment: @Francesca If you must use logs, write it as $\ln\bigl(\exp(a-0.1b)\bigr)$.

Comment: Hi David, thank you… I have only log(a) and log(b) and would like to express it as just these initial value, is this possible?

Comment: well you could also write the final answer $\ln(\exp(a-0.1b))$, but because the final answer is just $a-0.1b$ (so no logarithms at all) there is no 'natural' way without sort of forcing it to express your answer with just $\ln(a)$ and $\ln(b)$.

Comment: But forcing it to be expressed in terms of ln(a) and ln(b) is exactly what I would like to do… Is this impossible maybe?

Comment: yes, in that case your initial expression $\exp(\ln(a))-\exp(\ln(0.1)+\ln(b))$ is as good as it will get. Similarly it is impossible to re-write for instance just 10 as something involving $\ln(10)$, you can only get it as $\exp(\ln(10))$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Teun. Then I think this is an R question, since I have no idea how to compute the exponential of a number when it is too high (that is why I was trying to not exponentiate it).